# How to get current working directory in cpp?

Tags: c++

I'am familiar that getcwd() function is available in c to get current working directory.Is there a std function in cpp for the same?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**

C++17 has [`std::filesystem::current_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path).

On a POSIX system, you can also just keep using `getcwd()`. `getcwd()` is not actually part of C. Even it were, you could still keep using it, as the C Standard Library is available in C++; however, you've probably heard that it is preferable to use the C++ Standard Library where possible, and that's largely true.

Answer (score 0):

Use current_path() method in boost::filesystem or std::filesystem::current_path() in c++17